# What scopes are necessary to create JWT to access google APIs?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I need to access my FireBase Database via HTTP and I don't know what should I insert in `scope` field of the JWT claim set. In the docs, it reads "scope: A space-delimited list of the permissions that the application requests."
The path to my Database in Firebase is like `https://console.firebase.google.com/project/fir-19f8e/database/data` Is this what I should enter in scope?

```
let jwtClaimSet =
["iss":"firebase-adminsdk-c7i12345@fir-30c9e.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
 "scope":"",
 "aud": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
 "exp": "",
 "iat": ""]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the following scopes:

- `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database"`
- `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"`

You can learn more in the [Firebase Database REST API User Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth) docs.

Comment: Anyone who wants to make calls to google API's can find the full explanation how to make JWT and sign them. Also if you get error invalid signature, unsupported grant_type,  [here is the answer. It just works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696026/swiftvapor-requesting-oauth-token-for-service-account-with-error-unsupported-gr)

Comment: When I try to access Firebase Database, I get  error Permission Denied. [I posted the question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810233). I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why is it necessary to give to scopes parameter the value `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` when we only want to read/write firebase database using an access token received from OAuth2.0 server? I thought `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database` would be the only scope needed.