# Swift Vapor unsupported_grant_type invalid signature / OAuth access token

Tags: swift, oauth-2.0, vapor

I am running Xcode 8.1 with Vapor and SWIFT 3.

I am posting a request to to google server to get an auth token, so I can call FireBaseDB API, but I get error:   unsupported_grant_type/Invalid grant_type.
On [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) it says that I have to encode in a URL the following: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token + grant_type + assertion, and pass the encoded URL in the body of the POST request. I pass it as a string.

I have noticed that the private key from the JSON file downloaded from my service account contains characters such as /n , ----,==, should I delete them before posting the key?

```
    let dateNow = Date()
      var expDate = String(Int(dateNow.timeIntervalSince1970 + (60 * 60)))
        var iatDate = String(Int(dateNow.timeIntervalSince1970))


 let headerJWT = ["alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"]
    let jwtClaimSet =
    ["iss":"firebase-adminsdk-c7i48@fir-10c2e.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
     "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database",
      "aud":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
       "exp": expDate,
         "iat": iatDate]

      //create and sign JSON Web Token
   let jwt = try JWT(headers: Node(node: headerJWT),
              payload: Node(node: jwtClaimSet),
               signer: HS256(key:"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvAWvQ== \n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"))

    // Store JSON Web Token
      let JWTtoken = try jwt.createToken()

func createUrlWithString() -> NSURL {
    var urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
     urlString.append("?grant_type=")
      urlString.append("urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer")
       urlString.append("&assertion=")
        urlString.append(JWTtoken)
  return NSURL(string: urlString)!
 }

        // make the body input for our POST
      let bodyURL =  createUrlWithString().absoluteURL

     drop.get("any") { request in
        let response =  
 try drop.client.request(.other(method:"Post"),
           "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token", 
             headers: ["Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"], 
                 query: [:], 
                  body: String(describing: bodyURL) )


     let serverResp = response.headers
        let serverBody = response.body.bytes
          let serverJson = try JSON(bytes: serverBody!)
             print(serverJson)
    return "POST Request went through"
}
```

### Update

As per Karol Gasienica suggestion, I am passing `grant_type` and `assertion` parameters as POST request parameters. Now I get `"error_description": Node.Node.string("SSL is required to perform this operation.")]))`

```
func createUrlWithString() -> NSURL {
 var urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
  urlString.append("?grant_type=")
    urlString.append("urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer")
     urlString.append("&assertion=")
      urlString.append(JWTtoken)
  return NSURL(string: urlString)!
}

  let response =  try drop.client.request(.other(method:"Post"), 
   String(describing: bodyURL),
      headers: ["Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"], 
         query: [:])
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with swift but I think your alg param may be wrong. You specify (RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 with the SHA-256 hash ( aka "RS256") but you seem to  encode the jwt with HMAC SHA-256 ("HS256"). I suggest you to replace `"alg":"RS256"` with `"alg":"HS256"` as HS256 is only mandatory alg [0] https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate a service account credential you need to have in mind the following, taken from `https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication`:
You can create a private key in the Cloud Platform Console by creating an OAuth Client ID for a service account. You can get your private key in JSON and PKCS12 format:

JSON keys are required if you are using [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#libauth) in a production environment outside of Google Cloud Platform. **JSON keys cannot be converted to other formats.**
PKCS12 (.p12) is supported by many different programming languages and libraries. If needed, you can convert the key into other formats using OpenSSL ([see Converting the private key to other formats](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication)). However, PKCS12 keys cannot be converted to JSON format.

1. Create your service account and then download your .p12 file.
2. ## Convert the p.12 (a.k.a pkcs12) file to .pem (a.k.a pkcs1) using OpenSSL

`cat /path/to/xxxx-privatekey.p12 | openssl pkcs12 -nodes -nocerts -passin pass:notasecret | openssl rsa > /path/to/secret.pem`

3. Go to github and search [VaporJWT](https://github.com/siemensikkema/vapor-jwt) and import it in Xcode. It will help you create a signed JSON Web Token.
4. On this github page you will learn how to extract the private key for RSA use.
5. // convert .pem to der
   `openssl rsa -in /path/to/secret.pem -outform der -out /path/to/private.der`
6. //convert .der to .base64
   `openssl base64 -in /path/to/private.der -out /path/to/Desktop/private.txt`
   In private.txt you have the private key encoded in base64 which you can finally use to sign you JWT. Then you can make calls to Google API with the signed JWT.

```
import Vapor
import VaporJWT

  let drop = Droplet()
   var tokenID:String!

  //set current date
   let dateNow = Date()

// assign to expDate the validity period of the token returnd by OAuth server (3600 seconds)
  var expDate = String(Int(dateNow.timeIntervalSince1970 + (60 * 60)))

 // assign to iatDate the time when the call was made to request an access token
    var iatDate = String(Int(dateNow.timeIntervalSince1970))

// the header of the JSON Web Token (first part of the JWT)
let headerJWT = ["alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"]

// the claim set of the JSON Web Token
let jwtClaimSet =
   ["iss":"firebase-adminsdk-c7i38@fir-30c9e.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
     "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database",
       "aud":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
        "exp": expDate,
         "iat": iatDate]


//Using VaporJWT construct a JSON Web Token and sign it with RS256 algorithm
//The only signing algorithm supported by the Google OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server is RSA using SHA-256 hashing algorithm.

    let jwt = try JWT(headers: Node(node: headerJWT), payload: Node(node:jwtClaimSet), encoding: Base64URLEncoding(), signer: RS256(encodedKey: "copy paste here what you have in private.txt as explained at point 7 above "))

// create the JSON Web Token
 let JWTtoken = try jwt.createToken()
let grant_type = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer" // this value must not be changed
     let unreserved = "*-._"
      let allowed = NSMutableCharacterSet.alphanumeric()
        allowed.addCharacters(in: unreserved)

 // percent or URL encode grant_type
  let grant_URLEncoded = grant_type.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowed as CharacterSet)

 // create a string made of grant_type and assertion. NOTE!!! only grant_type's value is URL encoded.
 //JSON Web Token value does not need to be URL encoded
   var fullString = "grant_type=\(grant_URLEncoded!)&assertion=\(JWTtoken)"


 //pass fullString in the body parameter
 drop.get("call") { request in


     let response =  try drop.client.post("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token", headers: ["Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"], query: [:],body: fullString)

    let serverResp = response.headers
       let serverBody = response.body.bytes
          let serverJson = try JSON(bytes: serverBody!)
            print(serverJson)

return "Success"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you dont set properly `grant_type` in your code:

```
urlString.append("?grant_type=")
```

In your case it might be `grant_type=authorization_code`
or
`grant_type=jwt-bearer`

It seems like you set `grant_type` in wrong place.

**Update**

Also I think grant_type and assertion parameters are not passed as request headers but as post request parameters

**Update**

Im not really sure you are using correct way to put POST (body) parameters. In [this](https://vapor.github.io/documentation/http/client.html) documentation is example how to create request with post prams and it looks like follows:

```
try drop.client.request(.other(method: "POST"), "http://some-domain", headers: ["My": "Header"], query: ["key": "value"], body: [])
```

Comment: Is `grant_type` property an array of dictionaries? e.g var grant_type = ["urn":"value1","grant-type":"val2", "jwt-bearer":"val3"] . It is not very clear on [dev.google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). From [ietf stadanrd](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7523)  The value of the "grant_type" is "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-
   type:jwt-bearer".Can you explain me in code step by step what should I do? Thanks

Comment: Any ideea why OAuth server does not see I make a https POST request? Please see my updated question.

Comment: Check now, I see you are putting all your data in query (URL) and it should be in POST

Comment: I still get error unsupported grant_type. I think `var urlString` is not formatted with the correct components. What I am trying to achieve is [Client credentials grant](https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/). In JSON file I don't have `client_secret` key, but [private_key_id](http://imgur.com/a/P4mOq) . I put the code in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/bibscy/347d19745aae2b5d70c8f62716f867c4) . I think I no longer have to specify https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token in body of POST request, as it is already specified in the uri of the POST.

Comment: `createUrlWithString` doesn't this function just create an string? Documentation says that post can be send in `body: []` option as says example: `try drop.client.request(.other(method: "POST"), "http://some-domain", headers: ["My": "Header"], query: ["key": "value"], body: [ here_post_data])` but you are just putting a url `String(describing: bodyURL)` without any post data in `body`. URL cant contain POST data.

Comment: `createUrlWithString` creates a url of type: `NSURL`. I could simply `-> String` in the function above and then pass the the string in the body of the POST request. I cannot pass URL in the body of the POST request, that's why I converted it to a String. So, I am passing in the body of  POST reques an instance of `String` which takes as an argument `var bodyURL `, thus creating an object of type String with the contents of bodyURL.

Comment: The string that I am passing in the body of the POST request looks like this: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=1017561806708243261&private_key_id=8b157a8d8b6b4fde8aaa37bff94bc6cbdb73f3&assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvd3d3Lmdvb2dsZWFwaXMdsZXC9maXJlYmFzZS5kYXRhYmFzZSJ9.Td2v09dvLFgsaEVBRQh8HCRF+GdBNOOqisdj2XY9z4g=`

Comment: `grant_type=client‌​_credentials` still looks like it is in query not in body. So it's `$_GET` not `$_POST` even if you set to send data as POST. In POST you can have GET and POST data

Comment: I used print(bodyURL) so as to show you what the final String looked like. The string you see above is the value of bodyURL after all components are concatenated and bodyURL is passed as argument to `body` parameter of .request() function.

Comment: Do you know how can I extract the literal value from the private_key that I downloaded from my google service account? I turns out it is in pem encoded from what I read. 
[myfile](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/00772a7c130c2ad16b6e1dd3e1b9bce7)

Comment: Not really sorry :)

Comment: I found a solution. See my answer :)

Comment: Any idea why I get 403 Permission Denied when I try to access firebase database? My question is here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810233